# function1 from other file fail when that function1 is calling another function2 inside function1

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Code in FileB.py works fine, but fail at one point when I am calling it from other file. I found that it's stops working when calling function "search_response" in the code below.

FileA.py

```
from FileB import *
search = "stackoverflow"    
searchF(search)
```

FileB.py

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.errors import HttpError
from oauth2client.tools import argparser

search = "Google"    
def searchF(search):

  DEVELOPER_KEY = "REPLACE_ME"
  YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
  YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"
```

**print "searchF started" - works**

```
  def youtube_search(options):
    youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
      developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)

    search_response = youtube.search().list(
      q=options.q,
      type="video",
      part="id,snippet",
      maxResults=options.max_results
    ).execute()
```

**print "search_response executed" doesn't work**

```
    search_videos = []

    for search_result in search_response.get("items", []):
      search_videos.append(search_result["id"]["videoId"])
    video_ids = ",".join(search_videos)

    video_response = youtube.videos().list(
      id=video_ids,
      part='snippet, contentDetails'
    ).execute()

    videos = []

    for video_result in video_response.get("items", []):
      videos.append("%s, (%s,%s)" % (video_result["snippet"]["title"],
                                video_result["contentDetails"],
                                video_result["contentDetails"]))
    find = "licensedContent': True"
    result = ', '.join(videos)
    print find in result

  if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "__main__"
    argparser.add_argument("--q", help="Search term", default=search)
    argparser.add_argument("--max-results", help="Max results", default=25)
    args = argparser.parse_args()

    try:
      youtube_search(args)
    except HttpError, e:
      print "An HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s" % (e.resp.status, e.content)
```

Comment: You're only calling `youtube_search()` when `__name__ == "__main__"`. When you call `searchF()`, that's not true.

Comment: That `if` statement should be at top-level in the module, not inside a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `if __name__ == "__main__":` to `if 1:` and it's kinda works. But I am assume it's a horrible solution.